# Linq and Lambda Expression get count for group and distinct

Tags: asp.net

I've been trying to get the "Count" for my "Value" field in my query expression. In my code it suppose to create a list of checkboxes and beside the checkboxes is a count of how many items are in the list(checkbox).

Could someone show me how to get the count for the items of my field Value this is a checbox filtering system I'm making.I've just started learning linq and lambda exressions.

Code in C# ASP.NET

```
var dept = Page.RouteData.Values["department"];
var department = (from d in db.Departments where d.Name.Replace(" ", "-") == dept select new {d.Id, d.Name}).FirstOrDefault();

 var query = (from p in db.Products
              join f in db.ProductFilters on p.Id equals f.ProductId into filters
              from x in filters.Where(x => x.Product.DepartmentId == department.Id)                            
              select new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Value }).ToList();

 var brand = query.Where(x => x.Name == "Brand").OrderBy(x => x.Value);
 var price = query.Where(x => x.Name == "Price").OrderBy(x => x.Value);

 var brandAndPrice = brand.Concat(price);

 var labelBrandAndPrice = (from f in brandAndPrice select new { f.Name }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
 //var otherFilters = query.Except(brandAndPrice);

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("<div class=\"Filters\">");                
 foreach (var label in labelBrandAndPrice)
 {
     sb.Append("<span>" + label.Name + "</span><br />");
     sb.Append("<div class=\"ProdFilters\">");
     // Below is where I wanted to do distinct expression and groupby but it didn't work
     var BrandPriceCollection = brandAndPrice.Where(x => x.Name == label.Name).Distinct().ToList();
     foreach (var bp in BrandPriceCollection)
     {
        //Here i want to write out the count for the field Value 
        sb.Append("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + bp.Value + "\" /><span>" + bp.Value + "(" + "Count" + ")" + "</span><br />");
     }
     sb.Append("</div>");
 }               
 sb.Append("</div>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var BrandPriceCollection = brandAndPrice.Where(x => x.Name == label.Name).Distinct().ToList();
var groupings = BrandPriceCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Value);
foreach (var g in groupings)
{
   //Here i want to write out the count for the field Value 
   sb.Append("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + g.Key + "\" /><span>" + g.Key + "(" + g.Count() + ")" + "</span><br />");
}
```

`GroupBy` returns your data in the structure like Dictionary, with value you are grouping on in `Key` property and the collection of elements inside, so you can just `Count()` it. Note that `groupings` is the collection of collections now.

Comment: i'll give that ago and get back to you

Comment: I tried that and it worked I've learned something new today I think thanks heaps.